# Tuning Nvidia driver in Nvidia X Server Settings in Ubuntu to avoid tearing?

Tags: ubuntu, nvidia-ion

I'm running Ubuntu 10.10 on an Asus at3ion motherboard. I have installed the proprietary nvidia drivers and everything is working fine, but it's a but ragged when I move windows etc. I think the issue is called tearing. There is flickering and the window isn't refreshed smoothly.

The ion acceleration works fine (I am running xbmc at 1080p completely without any issues). Please note I am not interested in any fancy effects etc, I just want the graphics to be smooth and nice.

How can I tune the nvidia driver for this, i.e., what do I need to change in the Nvidia X Server Settings?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you're specifically seeking this, but I always add a PPA to apt-get which always contains the latest nVidia drivers. Link: [PPA for latest nVidia drivers for Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/ppas/27)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Installing the driver isn't the problem. It's setting it up, i.e., poking around in the Nvidia X Server Settings, I want some help with. I edited the question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

I dont have my linux box in front of me, so I cant check if it exists there or not.  But in the Nvidia xserver applet there *should* be a v-sync option that will synchronize your monitor’s Refresh Rate to the graphics card frame rate.  Enabling v-sync reduces screen tearing, however it may reduce overall frame rate.